# Desktop Environment dilemma

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, lubuntu, desktop-environments

I have a big dilemma.
I'm using Lubuntu right now, but!
I love the most Unity desktop environment, but it uses too much RAM.
I love Gnome-shell, but LXDE uses much less RAM.
Is there a Desktop Environment that uses small amount of RAM and is similar to Gnome-shell/Unity?

Comment: I thought gnome-shell and Unity were quite different... in fact anything and Unity is quite different, isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will I be able to get an interface that is like Gnome Classic in Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/441360/will-i-be-able-to-get-an-interface-that-is-like-gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-14-04), GNOME Classic desktop environment was similar to Unity but more lightweight, so a desktop environment in Ubuntu 14.04 that is like GNOME Classic may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

See almost all the different desktops here [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Other lower-ram desktops or window managers could be XFCE, MATE, Openbox, fluxbox, etc...

There are Ubuntu versions (official and derived) for almost all of them, try out some live iso's and see which one(s) you like.

Or you could install the desktop in question to your current system, but it could be a lot of unnecessary packages that would never get used again, and config changes that wouldn't have to be worried about.

Answer (score 0):

If you like look of Unity or Gnome with panel on the top :

1. XFCE
2. MATE

They are both lightweight and full-featured at the same time.
See the link: http://www.howtogeek.com/163154/linux-users-have-a-choice-8-linux-desktop-environments/