# Will Ubuntu MATE break Unity desktop?

Tags: unity, mate, ubuntu-mate

I'm currently running ubuntu 14.04. I installed gnome alongside unity and it seems to work without issue using lightdm as the default display manager (using gdm as default previously broke unity). My question is, can I install Ubuntu Mate alongside Unity and Gnome without conflicts? I've read that Ubuntu Mate may cause instability when installed alongside Unity. I want to be able to use both Unity and Mate. Based on your experience, should I install mate-desktop-environment instead?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Related question: [Will I be able to get an interface that is like Gnome Classic in Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/441360/will-i-be-able-to-get-an-interface-that-is-like-gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: So it seems its safer to install the mate desktop for now. Thanks karel.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just installed the MATE Desktop Environment, and it works fine if Unity is already installed. You obviously can't use them at the same time, but they can both be installed.

Comment: how does switching happens ?

Comment: @EbuzerTahaKANAT Logout, click on the user at the login screen, before signing in, click the little wheel icon: it gives you the option between the different desktop environments.