# change flavours from Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) to MATE 15.04

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, mate

Is there a way to change flavours from Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet)
to MATE 15.04  without downgrading back to 14.10 first?

Comment: http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download

Comment: wiki.mate-desktop.org/download Does not provide me with a solution.

Comment: "MATE 1.8 has been available in official repositories since Ubuntu 14.10."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will I be able to get an interface that is like Gnome Classic in Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/441360/will-i-be-able-to-get-an-interface-that-is-like-gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: list of packages available http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/mate-desktop-environment

Comment: I will repeat,  "wiki.mate-desktop.org/download " does NOT provide any instruction / command line info for being able to switch from 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) to MATE 15.04 . Unless im missing something PLEASE INDICATE to me where you would find the info that I am requesting. It simply is NOT there

Answer (score 2):

Ok got it , it was staring me right in the face!

First make sure your package list is up-to-date by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install MATE, choose one of the apt-get options below.

- This will install the base packages required for a minimal MATE desktop

  ```
  sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-core
  ```
- This will install the complete MATE desktop

  ```
  sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment
  ```
- This will install the complete MATE desktop including a few extras

  ```
  sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-extras
  ```

Comment: but then you also have to uninstall all the other desktop stuff