# Xorg memory leak - Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, radeon, memory-leak

After some time that the computer runs, Xorg starts using ridiculous amounts of RAM: On startup it uses only 50-80 MB, after a few hours it reaches 400-600 MB, and after 2-3 days it can reach more than 1.2 GB(!) on a 3 GB RAM machine (I'm using Task Manager to see the RAM usage).

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Is there a way to reduce the memory without rebooting/logging out?

I was considering to try installing [Oibaf graphics drivers](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) - is it a good idea? Might it solve the problem?

**Update:** Tried Oibaf's ppa, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04.1 on a Dell Inspiron N4030.

here is the output of `sudo lshw -C video`

```
 *-display              
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fbe20000-fbe2ffff memory:fbe00000-fbe1ffff
```

Comment: to the close voters: this problem didn't go away on it's own (it didn't go away at all - I just stopped using that desktop environment because of it). And a solution would have helped e.g. this user - https://askubuntu.com/questions/980192/xorg-filling-up-memory-on-xubuntu?rq=1 who describes essentially the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to MATE desktop environment to avoid the problem. See 
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441360/will-i-be-able-to-get-an-interface-that-is-like-gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-14-04/441401#441401).

Comment: @Thomas well I agree that this doesn't really solve my problem, just bypasses it. I wanted to put it as a possible solution for anyone that might encounter the problem as well and just wants to continue working. If you still prefer I can put it as a comment...