# Xorg filling up memory on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, ram

Does anyone have a solution to xorg gradually filling up ram over time..? I have a PC left on all day, every day, and after a day or 2 the memory indicator shows that it begins to get to capacity (4gb) The computer is using 4 GPUs however and RAM usually not used much in the processes running.

I've searched for a solution and cannot find one, I did find those with a similar problem used:

```
$ ps aux --sort -rss | head -n15
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     1091  4.1 14.0 800752 522008 tty7    Ssl+ 10:01  18:01 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

to see what process is using RAM, the readout shows xorg (at 14% in this example, but this will increase over time again)

Any solution or workaround gratefully received, thanks!

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.5G        1.2G        1.7G         15M        642M        2.1G
Swap:          3.7G          0B        3.7G
```

Comment: Is it actually a problem? What does `free -h` show? Remember that unused RAM is wasted RAM, so the system will use a lot of it for caching. This is, however, not blocked and is still available to any program that needs it. See http://linuxatemyram.com .

Comment: Hi edited post to show output of free -h, thanks for your help! I'd say its a problem because as the RAM eventually fills up, that seems to coincide with PC crashing and freezing up, can't be sure its the cause however