# Is it normal for Ubuntu to use this much RAM?

Tags: ram

I have an **Asus N43L with 8GB RAM and Ubuntu 16.04 64bit** installed. When I check my RAM consumption while idle it's consuming almost 1GB. Is that to be expected?

Comment: Yes, it's normal. It all depends on what's running (there's always something running). Also,  Asus N43L has a Nvidia graphics. For better performance install the recommended driver version in Additional Drivers.

Comment: And this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/872980/ubuntu-16-04-heating-up-issue#comment1355191_872980 . Are you still using the same unsupported kernel?

Comment: for now i used additional driver ver 367.57 (propietary, tested) and my kernel still ver 4.9.2 i dunno if it supported kernel or not. how to find out? @CelticWarrior

Comment: I couldn't possibly write a better answer than the one already posted.

Comment: it's okay, your answer are very helpful bro... @CelticWarrior

Comment: @BrianMalubaya Please don’t put “solved” into the title. [Accept an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) instead.

Answer (score 5):

Your RAM usage is normal for Ubuntu 16.04. You can use whatever desktop environment you prefer or install multiple desktop environments so that you can switch from one DE to another.

Main memory access time is in the order of nanoseconds, and hard disk drive access time is in the order of milliseconds. It's normal for Ubuntu 16.04 to use up to 1.5GB RAM at idle if your computer has plenty of RAM to avoid using swap space which is much slower than RAM.

Comment: Well, nice explanation. And what version of DE you think lightest among them? and about swap capacity, is it ok if it just 2GB?

Comment: The default swap partition size is for your computer is probably 4-6.4GB. This is a conservative figure. Depending on the amount of RAM in your computer and your use case, your system may never use any swap space. Personally I always accept whatever default swap capacity the Ubuntu installer selects for me. The lightest desktop environment is LXDE. LXDE looks too much like Windows XP to me, so I prefer [MATE desktop environment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar/518968#518968).

Comment: hmm... i guess i'll try to do as you say. i like light desktop because i using it for office purpose. Anyway, thanks in advanced...

Comment: [How to install MATE in Ubuntu 14.10 and newer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/441360/will-i-be-able-to-get-an-interface-that-is-like-gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-14-04/441401#441401)